# is there any way to convert all of my table date to varchar rather than using ALTER?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have some problem like this... i was told to search some invalid database because an employe index number or (NIP) in indonesian is not the same as the birthdate of the worker for example : my birthdate is 1996-12-23 so the employe index number should be 19961223015 the last 3 digit is the worker serial number

i already using syntax called 'LIKE' so when i'm using it it almost like 'NIP not like TGLLHR' (the birthdate) of course the output is all of them  beacuse VARCHAR can't compared to DATE

```
select m.NIP, m.NAMA, DATE_FORMAT(m.TGLLHR, '%Y%m%d') as TGLLHR, DATE_FORMAT(m.TMTCAPEG, '%Y%m%d') as TMTCAPEG, m.KDJENKEL, m.KDSTAPEG, s.NMSTAPEG, t.KDSATKER, t.NMSATKER
from mstpegawai m join
     stapeg_tbl s
     on m.KDSTAPEG=s.KDSTAPEG join
     satker_tbl t
     on m.KDSATKER=t.KDSATKER
where m.KDSTAPEG < 10 AND
      (NIP not like TGLLHR OR  NIP not like TMTCAPEG OR  NIP not like KDJENKEL)
ORDER BY m.NAMA
```

i expect the output would be like this 
NIP 19931215013 but the birthdate is 1993-11-15 so that mean the data is invalid because the first number of NIP is not the same as the birthdate

Comment: Concatenating additional information into a primary key column is a bad database design to begin with.

Comment: sorry i'm using oracle for this

Comment: There is no function `DATE_FORMAT()` in Oracle - did you mean MySQL?

Comment: wait what?? really? my bad then.... i'm new at this T_T

Comment: Why not just cast... `WHERE nip NOT LIKE CONCAT(CAST(TGLLHR as varchar(20), '%'))` ? (Added the `CONCAT` with a wildcard in there too since you are using `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date to a string using a date mask, in order to guarantee that it is converted exactly as you expect.

Assuming that `TGLLHR` is a `DATE` column, do the comparison as such:

```
NIP not like TO_CHAR(TGLLHR, 'YYYYMMDD') || '%'
```

If you simply cast the `DATE` field as `VARCHAR2`, then you are letting Oracle use your `NLS_DATE` settings to perform an implicit date conversion, something that you probably don't want. Use the explicit date mask.